# Changing values of slope along polyline to 0 using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, conditional

In ArcGIS 10.1 (advanced license), I have a slope raster of a given area and a polyline.

I want to set the slope values along the polyline to 0.

I'm thinking of this process - extract the cells along the polyline using the `Extract by Mask tool`, then reclassifying those cells giving a `0 value`, and then using a `conditional statement in Raster Calculator` to substitute (in the general area's slope raster) the polyline cells with those cells which now have 0s.

I am not sure this is a good solution and I cannot figure out what the conditional statement should look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the polyline to raster tool and set the slope raster as the extent and snap raster in the tool environment settings. Use a Con statement in the raster calculator tool:

```
Con(IsNull("yourlineraster"), "yoursloperaster", 0)
```